# If a binary number is greater or equal than another one, does it have the same or more number of digits?

Tags: solution-verification, binary, binary-operations

This question came up to my mind while dealing with complexity of binary operations, speciffically with multiplication.

**The question.** Let's say we have two binary numbers $n$ and $m$, such that $n \geqslant m.$ Can we guarantee (only with this information) that the number of digits of $n$ (say $k$) is greater or equal than the number of digits of $m$ (say $l$), i.e, can we guarantee that $k \geqslant l?$

**My thoughts.** This obviously should be a trivial question but I was unable to find an answer for it with a quick search on the internet. Therefore, I started thinking: Firstly, by contraposition, it suffices to show that if $l > k$, then $m > n.$ Therefore, let us fix arbitrary binary numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $l>k.$ The worst case scenario (where our thesis is most likely to fail) is if $m$ is just a sequence of zeros that ends in a $1$, i.e., if $m = 10\dots 0$ and $n$ is a sequence of ones with exactly one less digit than $m$ (here, we are just picking the smallest possible value for $m$ and the highest possible value for $n$). Therefore, transforming into decimal we can say that $(k = l-1)$

$$ m = 2^{k} \quad \text{ and } \quad n = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^i. $$

Now, it suffices to see that

$$ n = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^i = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} 2^i = 1 + \frac{2(1-2^{k-1})}{1-2} = 1 - 2 + 2^k = 2^k - 1 < 2^k = m, $$
proving what's wanted.

Is this result true and are my thoughts behind it acceptable?

Comment: Yes and that is true in every basis because of the identity $\sum_{j=0}^{x-1} (b-1)b^j=b^{x}-1$

Comment: Thanks @SassatelliGiulio , really clarifying.

Comment: $1\gt 0$ and each has one bit.

Comment: @JohnDouma Perhaps if we let $n,m \neq 0?$

Comment: $11\gt 10$ so ...

Comment: @JohnDouma My result states "if $n \geqslant m$ then $k \geqslant l$". This still covers the cases if $n > m$ but $k = l,$ which are the cases you are stating, I believe.

Comment: I read "necessarily more digits", but yeah, the greater than or equal case is true.

Comment: @JohnDouma You are giving examples where numbers have the same amount of digits but one is greater than another. If I state $l  > k$ then $m > n$ means if one number has STRICTLY more digits then it is greater. Where do your counterexamples contradcit any of this?

Comment: It doesn't. Your question said "more" which means greater than. Greater than or equal translates to "at least as many" in English. My first counter-example was $3\gt 2$ where $11\gt 10$ but the number of bits is two in each case. Do you understand? I was going by your question in your title: that is false.

Comment: @JohnDouma Oh, so my title and the body are saying different things, is that it? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Have you read [OEIS sequence A070939](https://oeis.org/A070939) "Length of binary representation of n"? The sequence is monotone nondecreasing.